# How to create trigger that updates field on parent with the sum from 2 children

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

- Updated to include screenshot - I need to create a trigger to update a field on a parent table with the sum of the values from two child tables. When the parent record is saved it should calculate ParentTotalEmployees = Sum(CountryTotEmployees) + Sum(StateTotEmployees). I can get it to populate if I only reference one child table but I haven't been able to figure out how to include the second child table.

[image]

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DD_UpdateTotEmp] ON [dbo].[DEALDATA] 
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
;WITH GrandTotCountry AS ( 
SELECT c.QDEALDATA1,
       SUM(QTOTCOUNTRYEMP) AS TotCountryEmp
FROM 
DEALDATA1 c
GROUP BY c.QDEALDATA1  
), 

GrandTotState AS ( 
SELECT c.QDEALDATA,
    SUM(QNUMSTATEEMP) AS TotStateEmp
FROM 
   DEALDATA2 c
GROUP BY c.QDEALDATA)

UPDATE T1
SET T1.QGRANDTOTEMP = (SELECT TotCountryEmp 
                        FROM GrandTotCountry T2 
                        WHERE T2.QDEALDATA=i.QDEALDATA)
FROM DEALDATA T1
INNER JOIN Inserted i ON T1.QDEALDATA=i.QDEALDATA

END
```

OR THIS ONE

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[DD_UpdateTotEmp] ON [dbo].[DEALDATA] 
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE T1
SET T1.QGRANDTOTEMP = (SELECT SUM(QTOTCOUNTRYEMP) 
                        FROM DEALDATA1 T2 
                        WHERE T2.QDEALDATA=i.QDEALDATA)
FROM DEALDATA T1
INNER JOIN Inserted i ON T1.QDEALDATA=i.QDEALDATA

END
```

Sample Data

```
USE TEMPDB
GO
-- Parent Table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DEALDATA](
[QDEALDATA] [varchar](36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
[MATTERSYSID] [varchar](36) NULL,
[QGRANDTOTEMP] [numeric](12, 0) NULL )

GO

INSERT INTO DEALDATA VALUES ('1404fcb1','C333897E',NULL);
INSERT INTO DEALDATA VALUES ('a51f9f8a','8AE3F809',NULL);
GO

-- Country Emp Table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DEALDATA1](
[QDEALDATA1] [varchar](36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
[QDEALDATA] [varchar](36) NULL,
[QCOUNTRY] [varchar](40) NULL,
[QTOTCOUNTRYEMP] [numeric](12, 0) NULL )    
GO

INSERT INTO DEALDATA1 VALUES ('60ae5737','a51f9f8a','Monaco',5);
INSERT INTO DEALDATA1 VALUES ('62ceecb9','a51f9f8a','Australia',10);
INSERT INTO DEALDATA1 VALUES ('a645fcd1','1404fcb1','United States',100);
GO

-- State Emp Table 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DEALDATA2](
[QDEALDATA2] [varchar](36) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
[QDEALDATA] [varchar](36) NULL,
[QEMPSTATE] [varchar](40) NULL,
[QNUMSTATEEMP] [numeric](12, 0) NULL )
GO

INSERT INTO DEALDATA2 VALUES ('453b7b64','a51f9f8a','NY',50);
INSERT INTO DEALDATA2 VALUES ('e803b38f','a51f9f8a','KY',50);
INSERT INTO DEALDATA2 VALUES ('413954e1','1404fcb1','MO',20);
INSERT INTO DEALDATA2 VALUES ('ef2213e5','1404fcb1','HI',10);
GO
```

Thank you in advance in helping me with this.

Comment: I would be happy to help you create a trigger for this but I just can't wrap my head around the details. Can you post table definitions and a few rows of sample data? Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks Sean. I added scripts to add sample data.

Comment: Can you simply create a view instead of trying to constantly update your table? Seems to me like a view would be a much better idea than storing aggregate data that you have to constantly maintain. Just have an aggregate in your view and it will always be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger (insert, Update, and/or Delete) belongs to a particular table.  If you need a trigger on two tables (or many tables) you will need two triggers (or many triggers).

However, you can write a stored-procedure and call it from two triggers. And Since you have used after trigger, you don't need to use Inserted, Deleted objects.

It can be like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER Trigger1 ON Table1
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC‌ TheProcedure
END‌
```

and

```
ALTER TRIGGER Trigger2 ON Table2
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC‌ TheProcedure
END‌
```

As you see the notes bellow, the above code performance is really bad. The best you can do is to redesign your tables. However, if you prefer slight modification on your data base design, you can create two aggregate tables for your child tables and then use a VIEW‌ to combine them into a single result.

Comment: "And Since you have used after trigger, you don't need to use Inserted, Deleted objects." - that may be the single worst piece of advice I have seen this year. The original code was using inserted and deleted so it knows which rows to update. Your suggestion would update the entire table every single time. So when there are  a  million rows in the table but one being inserted this would force an update on a million rows instead of one.

Comment: you are wright about the performance. However, please keep it to yourself what have you seen or not. We all write here to help others no to express sentiments

Comment: But seriously, that is horrible advice.

Comment: Sure, I understand what you are saying and you are right. Unfortunately, when I was writing it, I only was thinking about having a piece of code in two places ( I mean inside two triggers). As you know this is not  a best practice to keep aggregation of two table inside parent table. Maybe @user3119773 needs to redesign the tables. In that case (merging the two table into one) he can keep the cache values inside the parent table even without using a trigger.

Comment: Yes agreed 100%. A redesign is the best approach here.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't redesign. The application I am using creates the tables for me. I'm very limited in what I can do.

Comment: In that case you need to have two separate triggers for two tables

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. Thanks to all who responded!

```
UPDATE dst
SET dst.GrandTotEmp = COALESCE(tot1.TotCountryEmp, 0) + COALESCE(tot2.TotStateEmp, 0)
FROM DEALDATA as dst
JOIN inserted AS i ON dst.QDEALDATA = i.QDEALDATA
LEFT JOIN GrandTotCountry AS tot1 ON tot1.QDEALDATA = dst.QDEALDATA
LEFT JOIN GrantTotState AS tot2 ON tot2.QDEALDATA = dst.QDEALDATA
```